# What is "are you"?

Tags: terminology, light-verbs

What is "**are you**" in the question

> "Are you going to the beach?"

I thought it might be a verb phrase but when I looked up the definition of this type of phrase in the *WJEC A Level English Language terminology glossary* it says

> "A phrase made up of a single lexical verb, or up to four auxiliaries
>   and a lexical verb"

Examples given along with the definition are:

> "follows, was following, should have been following, may have been
>   being followed".

Comment: "Are you" is auxiliary verb + subject. "Are" is just part of the predicate VP "are going to the beach".

Answer (score 1):

*Are* is the sentence's verb, the head word of the verb phrase *are going*.

*You* is the sentence's subject.

The order is V-S instead of S-V because it's a question.

Answer (score 0):

"be going to" is a pattern or idiom in English language. It means, that something will be done for sure. 

"am", "is", "are" - are forms of the verb "to be":

I am (not I be), You/We/They are (not you/we/they be) and He/She/It is (not He/She/It be)

For example:

- I am going to the beach. -- I strongly intend to go to the beach.
- She is going to the beach.
- You are going to the beach.

According to the English rules to form an interrogative question we should situate a main verb at the first place, but after a question word.

 In the sentences above the main verbs are: "am", "is", "are".

So, the interrogative questions are:

- Am I going to the beach?
- Is she going to the beach?
- Are you going to the beach?

We use the verb "are" with "you" regardless you address to a single person or to several people.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified tree diagram:

[image]

The clause exhibits subject-auxiliary inversion, as expected in this kind of interrogative construction. The auxiliary verb "are" is treated as a pre-nucleus related to the predicator which is represented by 'gap' in the nucleus clause, with both items cross-referenced with the subscript index *i*.

This may all seem a bit complex, but the tree is useful for analysing the functions of the subject and auxiliary verb in such interrogatives